# Does Mykonos have nightlife in September?

Tags: greece, islands, nightlife, seasonal, cyclades-islands

I'm planning to go to Mykonos (Greece) in September, I've read that it is "post-season", are there still any parties or it is often empty/more familiar on those days?

Answer (score 5):

September is not exactly 'post-season'. It's surely not gonna be like July and August but there are gonna be some parties till mid September and the island is not gonna be empty.

Here's a [blog](http://mygreecetravelblog.com/2016/01/26/mykonos-bar-club-openings-and-party-events-in-2016/) where they write about events in mykonos.

Answer (score 1):

The nightlife of Mykonos is intense from June to September! But if you rent a motorbike to Mykonos or some other means, do not drink and drive!